# Calling Perl with parameters from PHP: exec(), virtual(), etc

Tags: php, parameters, cgi, exec, virtual

I am trying to retrieve the output of a Perl cgi script that has parameters with a PHP page on Apache.  If my PHP is

```
<? echo exec('../cgi-bin/test.cgi'); ?>
```

then I get the correct output (but I can't use the parameters).  However, if my PHP is

```
<? echo exec('../cgi-bin/test.cgi?m=1'); ?>
```

then I get no output.  When I use virtual()

```
<? echo virtual('../cgi-bin/test.cgi?m=1'); ?>
```

I get a "Call to undefined function virtual()" error.

My Perl script is getting the parameters with

```
my $co = new CGI;
my $mobile = $co->param('m') || 0;
```

I can't run the script from the command line because the shared hosting provider set the server that way.

Comment: Are you running Apache? According to virtual documentation: "virtual() is an Apache-specific function"

Comment: Regarding that second command with the parameters, what happens if you run that from a command-line?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are grabbing your variables in the Perl script but it probably wants `<? echo exec('../cgi-bin/test.cgi "1"'); ?>`

Comment: @greg_diesel I included the answer to your question in my question now.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Halfstop I included the answers to your questions in my question now.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: @greg_diesel  I tried what you suggested.  The server returned a response that was the same as the response without the "1". Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer will help anyone else because it isn't technically calling the Perl script via CGI as I understand it, but greg_diesel let me to call the Perl script from PHP with multiple parameters:

```
exec('../cgi-bin/test.cgi "1" "2"');
```

and access the parameter in Perl with

```
$ARGV[0];
$ARGV[1];
```

etc. instead of CGI.

Answer (score 0):

On thing to consider since it is a server side request is that the perl script submittal of parameters may initiate the script, but return of data may come from a different perl script.  a connector/link between the two might be some form of unique identifier.

```
'../cgi-bin/test.cgi'
```

```
'../cgi-bin/run_test.cgi'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30398613)